# Unable to retrieve last save time of uploaded excel document on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am searching to find last save time of Excel document but I have no success. This problem has taken a lot of my time. Please have a look at my code and suggest why I am not able to get last save time of document on server.

This code runs perfectly on localhost:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks oBooks = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oBook = null;

object oMissing = Type.Missing;

try
{
    oExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oExcel.Visible = false;
    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(filePath);

    object oDocBuiltInProps = (object)oBook.BuiltinDocumentProperties;
    Type typeDocBuiltInProps = oDocBuiltInProps.GetType();

    // Get the Author property and display it.
    string strIndex = “Last Save Time”;
    string strValue;
    object oDocAuthorProp = typeDocBuiltInProps.InvokeMember(“Item”,
                                               BindingFlags.Default |
                                               BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                               null, oDocBuiltInProps,
                                               new object[] { strIndex });
    Type typeDocAuthorProp = oDocAuthorProp.GetType();
    strValue = typeDocAuthorProp.InvokeMember(“Value”,BindingFlags.Default |
                                               BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                               null, oDocAuthorProp,
                                               new object[] { }).ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(“The Excel file: ‘{0}’ Last modified value = ‘{1}'”, filePath, strValue))
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Have you tried logging errors / looking at the logs on the server?  Is Office/Excel installed on the server?!!

Comment: Grim, there are no errors and yes ,office is installed on server.

Comment: There must be SOME kind of error - otherwise how do you know it's not working?!  What's it returning?  What are expecting it to return?  Where are viewing the Console output on the server?  Are you running the same code on your dev machine and the server?  Have you tried writing to a log file instead of the console?  You have a Try in your code - is there a Catch?!  You really aren't giving folks a lot of information to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime to get the last modified date of the file?

Check this: [File.GetLastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_)

Comment: I want last save time of document not last modified date.

Comment: When the file is saved, even if it is by programming, the modified date gets changed. If you need when was the file uploaded to the server, then getting the last creation date should do the job. Or maybe you need when the file was last saved before it was uploaded to the server?

Comment: In the code example provided in the question, he's after the 'Last Save Time' document property stored within the Excel book.  So, yes, looks like the last time it was saved before being uploaded.